# IDE connect to VM as if programming locally

Tags: ubuntu, ide, vagrant, virtual-machine, phpstorm

Is there a way for me to have an IDE running in the Host side (PhpStorm) that connects to a VM (Vagrant etc) in such a way that I can edit a project that resides in the Guest side but feels like the project is in the Host side?

I know that I can use FTP or SSH to browse through the remote files, which treats the VM as a separate machine in the same network. However using this will make some PhpStorm features unusable like quick file searches, mapping of code definitions etc. I also know that I can just download the code to the host side and do a sync. But if I have many projects in the VM, it can be a bit tedious to download the sources first to get started. If I download few files first, then I can't do any search on other files. Is there a way to have a setup like this?

1. Guest holds the code
2. Guest has all the third party dependencies (memcache, etc)
3. IDE is in the Host side
4. IDE accesses code in Guest but treats it as a local code
5. Host Browser accesses output via accessing the Guest's URL (no problem here)

I currently have a Windows host and an Ubuntu guest on a VM. Now my workstation runs well with the guest running but when I fire up my PhpStorm IDE on Ubuntu, my Guest slows down to the point of being unusable. I have made optimizations to the Host, Guest and IDE but still the slow down persists. However when I use PhpStorm in the host side, my machine runs perfectly smooth, which lead me to pursue a setup described above.

I usually do my code work on a Linux environment but I need Windows tools every now and then too so a dual boot setup will not be good. I also tried mounting folders from Windows to guest via Vagrant config but because of symlink and file system incompatibilities, this did not work.

If you are having this kind of setup or if you think it is impossible, or an alternative is better, let me know. I can't seem to find any online resource from PhpStorm's site and Vagrant that can give me a clue to achieve this.

Comment: why dont you share your project folder with your VM, simple virtualbox sharing folder is not super fast but good enough, if you need more perf go for nfs sharing type. so you'll work on your host machine with all the tools you need, and the changes will be in sync on the VM so you can run and execute code there

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Oh you mean enable network sharing from Guest to Host and access the project using the //LOCAL-IP? That would definitely solve the filesystem issue. I'll try it later. Thanks!

Comment: could work but can be slow. you can try but I would suggest to use NFS in this case

Comment: Oh I went for Samba instead since it is the one installed and it is working properly, although there is definitely a performance impact when indexing and fetching files. I'll try NFS now. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately my windows pro does not have nfs support, only enterprise based on my reading. I may have spoken too soon, after editing files in my samba connected IDE, the frequent indexing is too much work and slows down my Host significantly so the network share solution will not do.

Comment: you can use `rsync` then and just make sure to initiate a [`rsync-auto`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html)